# Prove polynomial ring over a discrete valuation ring quotient by powers of maximal ideal is regular?

Tags: commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, regular-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$ be a discrete valuation ring, (of characteristic $p$ if you need).

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer.

Is the ring $\frac{R}{\mathfrak{m}^n}[x]$ regular?

Note that: Regularity can be checked at localisation of maximal ideals.

Comment: This is part of a general phenomenon: if $A$ is regular and $a\in A$ belongs to the square of a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$, then $A/(a)$ is not regular.

Comment: In your case $A=R[x]$, and $a=t^n$. Then $a\in M^2$, where $M=(\mathfrak m,x)$. In fact, the localization of $A$ at $M$ is not regular.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you very much, it's very helpful.